# Why am I getting null for document.getElementById here?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, domdocument, getelementbyid

**Codepen: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/YyWmOo?editors=101**

In [my app](http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/YyWmOo?editors=101), I have a simple array of div id names `media = ["twitter", "news", "blogs"]`

I then have a simple for loop which attempts to grab the #ids from the markup and add them into my `vm.parameters` object.

Currently the div's are showing as `null`:

[image]

---

**Code in my Controller:**

```
var vm = this;
    vm.parameters = {};

var media = ['twitter', 'news', 'blogs'];

console.log(vm);
console.log(media);

initParameters();

function initParameters() {
    console.log('initParameters called...');
    for (var i=0; i<media.length; i++) {
        vm.parameters[media[i]]       = {};
        vm.parameters[media[i]].start = 0;
        vm.parameters[media[i]].limit = 10;
        vm.parameters[media[i]].total = 0;
        vm.parameters[media[i]].div   = document.getElementById(media[i]);
        console.log('getElementById =',document.getElementById(media[i]));
    }

    console.log('media = ',media);
    console.log('vm.parameters = ',vm.parameters);
}
```

Markup (Using the [Ionic framework](http://ionic.io/)):

```
<ion-slide id="twitter">
    <h3>Twitter stream</h3>
    <p>Here is content for Twitter</p>
</ion-slide>
<ion-slide id="news">
    <h3>News stream</h3>
    <p>Here is content for News</p>
</ion-slide>
<ion-slide id="blogs">
    <h3>Blogs</h3>
    <p>Here is content for blogs</p>
</ion-slide>
```

Comment: can you post your `html` to check your div's

Comment: Sorry, just added! Also here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/YyWmOo?editors=101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do an `onload` event before trying to get the id's. This is because the controllers run before the DOM loads:

```
window.onload = function(){
    initParameters();
}
```

Comment: window.onload isn't appropriate .. route changes occur after page loads making it fairly useless

Comment: @charlietfl If it's useless [why does it work](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojzvvK?editors=101)?

Comment: and if enter from different route?

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I ended up moving my code around into a function that is ready after page load

Answer (score 1):

DOM code doesn't belong in controllers. The controller will run before the route template is even loaded so you are looking for elements that don't exist yet.

Generally there shouldn't be any need to look for `elementById` . Normally you would let your data model drive creation of the view

If you must do dom manipulation like this you need to do it in a directive to be assured the element(s) exist when your code runs

Comment: Thanks! Yeah.... I was going quick, normally I only use Directives... but found this quick template.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    // your code
});
```

in your `angular.run()`, will execute once content loaded.